# Как выглядит архитектура правильных ASP.NET приложений?

Tags: ооп, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, проектирование, архитектура

Здравствуйте. Я уже год пытаюсь программировать на asp.net mvc, но я до сих пор не понимаю, как правильно проектировать архитектуру, так как я никогда не видел кода опытных разработчиков. У меня есть разрозненное понимание того как нужно проектировать по теории(декомпозиция, разделение ответственностей, всякие принципы типа SOLID и тд.), но я совершенно неспособен спроектировать систему.

Я хочу научиться делать действительно качественные системы поддерживающие TDD и тд. Буду очень признателен если какой-то опытный программист покажет мне пример своей архитектуры или посоветует что делать в таких случаях. Всем спасибо!

Comment: про "правильную" архитектуру можно долго спорить, так как это понятие сильно зависит от конкретной задачи и ситуации в проекте, но могу посоветовать примеры "симпатичных" решений (вы ведь именно их ищите в первую очередь, как я полагаю):

http://sharparchitecture.net/

http://prodinner.codeplex.com/

Comment: Посмотрите open-source проекты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый вечер!

Для начала советую почитать вот эту книгу -

http://download.microsoft.com/documents/rus/msdn/ры_приложений_полная_книга.pdf

А от себя дам совет

Прежде чем начинать проектировать и уж тем более реализовывать сложную систему, нужно иметь представление в своей голове как она будет работать. Затем зарисовать эскизы самого проекта и исходя из них начать планировать структуру классов и модулей будущего приложения.

Затем UML, UML и еще раз UML. И только после этого можно начинать писать систему.

P.S. По поводу поделиться кодом, вряд ли, кто либо, даст Вам такую возможность. Чтобы понять как построена архитектура, нужно получить не только сам код но и полную **спецификацию к нему**, а большинство из нас либо связаны договором о неразглашении коммерческой тайны либо личными мотивами. Да и полный код своего приложения вряд ли кто даст.

Начните с книг и увас появятся **конкретные вопросы** и мы тут вам все будем рады помочь :)

Удачи!

Comment: Я прошу только диаграмму классов в том же UML. Это бы мне дало какой-то толчок к мышлению.

Comment: В поддержку предыдущего ответа. Советую почитать вот эти книги Мартина Фаулера
1. "Архитектура корпоративных программных приложений"
2. "Рефакторинг"

Диаграмма классов плагина для работы Вконтакте
http://skachate.ru/pars_docs/refs/4/3828/3828_html_7da0a3ec.png

Ну и впринципе посмотреть - http://skachate.ru/informatika/3828/index.html?page=13


А по UML настоятельно советую пройти курс - http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1007/229/info

Comment: @jojo97 боюсь, диаграммы классов вам много не дадут. Точно также, разобрав компьютер вы вряд ли сможете понять принцип его рбаоты

Comment: Книгу "Архитектура корпоративных программных приложений" читал. А за остальное спасибо.

Comment: @jojo97

- Хотелось бы отметить, что лично я ни разу не сталкивался с ситуацией, когда UML "до" был бы хоть как-нибудь полезен. "После" (например, чтобы наглядно проиллюстрировать какое-то решение) — пожалуйста, но серьезное проектирование "до" — это огромный шаг в сторону [Waterfall model.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model)

- Отталкивайтесь от вашей глобальной задачи, декомпозируйте ее на более мелкие и жадным образом решайте эти мелкие задачи. Под "жадностью" здесь имеется ввиду, что текущая архитектура должна хорошо решать текущую задачу. Про все остальное забудьте.

Comment: @jojo97

- Если в какой-то момент вы понимаете, что текущая архитектура уже не позволяет хорошо решить текущую задачу, то остановитесь, подумайте, проведите рефакторинг. Тесты помогут вам избежать регрессии в том, что уже было сделано.

- Есть еще одна деталь — вы можете почувствовать, что не способны понять, хорошо ли текущая архитектура решает текущую задачу. Тут есть два пути: читайте больше чужого кода и развивайте свое чутье (1), либо забейте и продолжайте решать задачи (2). (1) — это превентивный способ, (2) — это способ, в котором вы быстрее дойдете до этапа, когда нужен рефакторинг.

Answer (score 2):

Вы хотите, чтобы вам в рамках одного ответа (то есть 5-15 предложений) ответили на такой вопрос? Боюсь, это невозможно. Если бы можно было  таким нехитрым образом научиться создавать правильную архитектуру, то разработчики, способные спроектировать и разработать приложение (будь то asp.net mvc, или что-то еще) ценились бы очень низко. А пока что они ценятся достаточно высоко. Более того, вы вряд ли сможете получить ответ на этот вопрос и в рамках целой статьи. 
  Можно, конечно, дать ряд общих советов о необходимости тщательно прорабатывать    требования к системе и приступать к разработке только после их детального описания, о пользе ТЗ, об отделении бизнес-логики от интерфейса, о создании слабосвязанных  архитектур,  о "программируйте на уровне интерфейсов, а не реализаций", долго и нудно разглагольствовать про нормализацию баз данных, о пользе UML и тд и тп. Но каждый из таких советов (а их может быть очень много)  требует даже не отдельного пояснения, а  отдельного обстоятельного рассказа. Но это даже полбеды. Другие полбеды кроются в том, что просто рассказ даст вам очень немного. Вам надо самостоятельно опробовать всё это в деле чтобы ощутить пользу (или бесполезность) тех или иных "серебряных пуль"
Словом, не ждите простого ответа на ваш вопрос. Читайте умных дяденек и тетенек (Буч, Фаулер, Макконнелл), пробуйте на практике то, что из них вычитаете, спроектируйте от начала и до конца какое-нибудь приложение (не обязательно с надеждой создать второй Фэйсбук, наоборот, лучше вовсе без нее), и, возможно, результат не заставит себя ждать (впрочем, может, и заставит)

Comment: Ну так посоветуйте умные книжки по этому поводу, пожалуйста:)

Comment: так я ж вам посоветовал - там в скобочках, почти в самом конце есть три фамилии. Погуглите по ним - они писали очень хорошие книжки, из которых можно почерпнуть для себя немало полезного и по вашему вопросу)

Comment: Я заметил фамилии, но они наврняка написали и хорошие и не очень книжки, и вы бы облегчили мне жизнь если бы сказали, которые книжки хорошие. Но и на том спасибо!

Comment: Скажем, книг у них было немало, поэтому в комментарии они не уместятся. Поэтому найдите, например, в Википедии странички об этих замечательных людях, и в конце каждой из них сможете увидеть список их книг

Answer (score 0):

Смотри [тут](http://tnimas.com/blog/mvc-begin-part-1/) неплохая статейка